# Visual Studio 2022 - how to link an .obj file residing somewhere else on the system?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, nasm, dynamic-linking, object-files

I had to write a small `.obj` file in NASM (call it `nasm.obj`). Next, I need to make Visual Studio 2022 to link my DLL against `nasm.obj`. How can I accomplish that? (Basically, all I need is to tell the VS to look in a specific folder which contains the desired `nasm.obj`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the `.obj` file in the Windows Explorer to the **Source Files** subtree in **Solution Explorer**.